# Weird issue: Not able to load the JAR in Android for BB 10 Android Run Time

Tags: android, blackberry-10, android-sdk-tools, blackberry-android

I updated Android SDK to 4.2.2 as well as eclipse plugin 1.6  for BB for BB 10 android run time,I am using .jar file for my encryption in my application.But when app is invoking of JAR file,it is not able to take the instance.it shows exception such as NoClassFoundException

I changed the signature Key for BB 10 android runtime and developer certificate.Is this issue related to android SDK or BB 10 Signing key?

Other workspace which does not have Change in code has same issue.

Can anyone provide suggestions to recover from this issue.

Comment: Where have you placed jar file ?

Comment: I placed in the lib folder,I have one more doubt Is bb 10 is supporting old Android 2.3.3 Runtime with their latest eclipse plugin or they suppoting only 4.2.2,Do you have idea over it

Comment: Rename the folder to libs and make your you application refers to libs folder in buildpath. Try this.

Comment: I renamed to libs,But Very first it was libs only,After Changing to libs,it started to work,I have same issue in some other workspace,Still not able to resolve the isssue,But issue got solved in other workspace,I still not cannot identify the what is difference

Comment: It is basically related to android, by default android looks for libs folder to get jars and libraries associated with the project. I assume it was changed some time before. If it worked for you I am posting it in answers section. Please accept.

Answer (score 0):

Rename the folder to libs and make sure your application refers to libs folder in buildpath. Try it. I hope it will resolve the issue.